How to set-up Redshift Connection on dBeaver CE when using Configuration file on a Mac
I am trying to set-up a Redshift connection using dBeaver CE.  I am trying to use the Configuration file option as described in the linked AWS Doc
Using a Configuration Profile


You can supply the IAM credentials options and GetClusterCredentials options as
settings in named profiles in your AWS configuration file. To provide the profile
name, use the Profile JDBC option. The configuration is stored in a file named
config or a file named credentials in a folder named .aws in your home directory.

I have not been able to determine how to supply the GetClusterCredentials options as settings in the named profile that will allow me to connect to Redshift.  I also looked at this Configuration and credential file settings doc, but not sure which of those are GetClusterCredentials options
How should I supply the options so that I can use dBeaver to connect to Redshift to execute my SQLs instead of having to login to console all the time?
Update
I was successfully able to run the below command on commandline and get the expected result
aws redshift get-cluster-credentials --cluster-identifier <cluster-name> --db-user <db-usernam> --db-name <db-name> --duration-seconds 3600 --profile <profile-name>
